# are my reboot-logs incorrect?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, logs

I´ve recently taken a look at my *reboot-logs* with  `last -x | grep reboot` :

```
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Mon Aug 27 12:36   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Sun Aug 26 12:18   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Sat Aug 25 13:22   still running
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Sat Aug 25 12:56 - 13:21  (00:25)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Thu Aug 23 12:40 - 13:21 (2+00:41)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Wed Aug 22 12:46 - 19:04  (06:17)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Tue Aug 21 11:37 - 18:48  (07:11)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Mon Aug 20 12:43 - 18:48 (1+06:05)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Sun Aug 19 12:02 - 18:48 (2+06:46)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Sat Aug 18 11:54 - 19:02  (07:08)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Fri Aug 17 12:23 - 18:35  (06:12)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Thu Aug 16 18:27 - 19:03  (00:35)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Thu Aug 16 12:28 - 19:03  (06:34)
```

Here it occurred to me that the first entry is correct. Well, my system is running right now, so that´s o.k.

Yet the following two entries make no sense at all. Yesterday (Sun Aug 26) and the day before (Sat Aug 25) it shut down my computer as I always do.

A normal clean shutdown. Despite that fact there´s the entry "still running".
But not so with all the other preceding entries.

And  `last -x | grep shutdown`  shows me the following:

```
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Sat Aug 25 13:21 - 13:22  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Wed Aug 22 19:04 - 12:40  (17:35)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Tue Aug 21 18:48 - 12:46  (17:57)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Sat Aug 18 19:02 - 12:02  (16:59)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Fri Aug 17 18:35 - 11:54  (17:18)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Thu Aug 16 19:03 - 12:23  (17:19)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Wed Aug 15 19:06 - 12:28  (17:21)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-131-generi Sun Aug 12 13:13 - 13:14  (00:00)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-131-generi Sat Aug 11 14:31 - 14:26  (23:54)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-131-generi Thu Aug  9 19:05 - 12:55 (1+17:50)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-131-generi Thu Aug  9 16:12 - 16:30  (00:17)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-131-generi Wed Aug  8 19:03 - 12:31  (17:27)
```

It´s odd that yesterday´s shutdown (Sun Aug 26) doesn´t show up at all. And again: I performed a normal shutdown.

Does anybody know what´s going on here?

P.S.:
my system: Lubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

*****UPDATE*****

Hi again.

I´m glad to tell that I somehow could get things straight again. But I really don´t know how exactly it worked out.

(Background: Dual-boot installation: WIN 8.1 and Lubuntu)

What I did the day before yesterday was the following:

1.) I booted up WIN. I had a vague feeling that it could have something to do with it......
I realized that the boot process look longer that ususal.

2.) It seemed that a reboot was pending as I got a message from avira (third party software, antivirus) which
told me to reboot. That I did.

3.) After a reboot I used WIN for a while and in the evening I performed a normal shutdown.

4.) The next day (yesterday) I booted up Lubuntu and saw with `last -x | grep -E '(reboot)|(shutdown)'` that 
nothing has changed. Well, I thought, that was to be expected.

5.) So I performed a normal shutdown and the booted up Lubuntu again.
Here are the results:

```
last -x | grep -E '(reboot)|(shutdown)'
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Wed Aug 29 14:34   still running
shutdown system down  4.4.0-134-generi Wed Aug 29 12:33 - 14:34  (02:01)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Wed Aug 29 14:25 - 12:33  (-1:-51)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Tue Aug 28 13:56 - 12:33  (22:37)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Tue Aug 28 13:12 - 12:33  (23:21)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Tue Aug 28 12:20 - 12:33 (1+00:13)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Mon Aug 27 14:57 - 12:33 (1+21:36)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Mon Aug 27 12:36 - 12:33 (1+23:57)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Sun Aug 26 12:18 - 12:33 (3+00:15)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-134-generi Sat Aug 25 13:22 - 12:33 (3+23:11)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Sat Aug 25 13:21 - 13:22  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Sat Aug 25 12:56 - 13:21  (00:25)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Thu Aug 23 12:40 - 13:21 (2+00:41)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Wed Aug 22 19:04 - 12:40  (17:35)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Wed Aug 22 12:46 - 19:04  (06:17)
shutdown system down  4.4.0-133-generi Tue Aug 21 18:48 - 12:46  (17:57)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-133-generi Tue Aug 21 11:37 - 18:48  (07:11)
[...]
```

As can be seen there is a shutdown entry this time and only one still running entry.

I really don´t know whether all this really had something to do with WIN and the fact that there was a reboot pending. After all it was just a wild guess. 
But somehow it worked out and the Lubuntu logs display the entries as would be expected.